# What's the best way to remote control a Raspberry pi - powered robot?

Tags: python, python-3, connection, radio, sockets

I'm going to build a robot powerd by raspberry pi and i wnat to control it remotely,
the principal tasks that need to have a remote exchande of data is:

- the streaming of 3 cameras
- the monitoring of the temperature and of the battery level
- the I/O for servo

Now, I'm a complete beginner to this, but i have some programming experience in python,

my question is what's the best thecnology to use to achieve the above tasks and a good compromise within:

- communication speed
- communication distance
- ram usage

I thougt about socket or radio antenna, but any thecnology will be ok.

I want to create my own GUI for controlling it with a little shell and the real time data from cameras, temperature and battery level.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for this site.  You will be better off asking such a broad non-specific question on raspberrypi.org/forums

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try a web interface with flask if your remote device and controller are both connected to wifi - here's some links to help you with that

[Intro to flask on raspberry pi](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/python-web-server-with-flask)

[Flask video streaming](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited)

[Using GPIO with flask](http://mattrichardson.com/Raspberry-Pi-Flask/index.html)

Hope that helps and good luck with your project :)

Comment: thank you very much for you useful suggestion, but i have a question, can  i use flask to comunicate between two scripts?, i've never used it before